# Moved Xcode To New Mac, Can't Build With Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning-profile

Ok, I moved all my Xcode projects to my new MBP.  After doing this, I am trying to get my new app build to submit to Apple.  I have the Distribution Provisioning Profile installed on my computer and set in the app, but under Distribution setting, it shows iPhone Developer, instead of iPhone Distribution.  What am I forgetting to do?

[image]

Comment: Did you update your new Mac's keychain with your certificates? Did you install all of your provisioning profiles on the new Mac?

Comment: As the question states...I have the Distribution Provisioning Profile installed on my computer.  I didn't do anything with Certificates

Comment: You should have properly backed up your certificates from the old machine and loaded them on the new machine. Nothing will work without the certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up revoking my old certificate, requesting a new one, adding that to Keychain, updating my provisoning profiles for that, and it worked finally.

Answer (score 2):

You should export your developer profile from your old mac. You can find this in Xcode --> Preferences --> Accounts. Bottom left corner, gear icon. Save the file to your desktop, and import the developer profile on your new mac via the same mechanism, selecting import this time. This should set you up.

Comment: I no longer have the old mac.